# Get color of terminal output / color of text returned

Tags: python, sockets, colors, terminal, pwntools

I am currently trying to automate a simple color reading test. I connect to the service with nc and it gives me a text in a certain color and then prompts the user to name the colored text above.

This would look something like this:
nc  
Here is your color: color! (e.g green)

> green

OK!

Here is your color: color! (e.g blue)

> red

ERROR! NOT OK!

exiting...

My current code looks something like this however I do not know how to implement it.

```py
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import socket
    from pwn import *

    hostname='ip'
    port=777

    r = remote(hostname, port)

    def recv(string):
            print r.recv()
            print r.recvuntil(string)

    def send(string):
            print r.send(string)

    #Loop through orders and check for order
    while True:

            recv("Here is your color:")
            color=r.recvuntil("color!") #Receive color
            print "Color is:" + command
            recv(">") #Receive until input prompt

            if color=green: #Check which color
                    send("green")
            else:
                    send("else")
```

The solution should make it run through endlessly without the having the user to prompt anything.

Comment: Have you examined the strings you’re receiving to see what control codes they use for color?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it now.
I found the color by printing the raw version of the received string.

```
repr(color)
```

For a green text this resulted:

> \x1b[92mGreen

Then I simply checked if the color identifier (\x1b[92m) is in the string.